# Unable to Save Logs to mongodb Database for winston-nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, logging, winston

I am using the winston library: https://github.com/flatiron/winston
Attempting to store data to the mongodb database with: https://github.com/indexzero/winston-mongodb

to insert the data I use:

```
var MongoDB = require('winston-mongodb').MongoDB;
var logger = new (winston.Logger)({
transports: [
    new (winston.transports.Console)(),
    new (winston.transports.MongoDB)({ host: ip,  db: 'caribcultivate', collection: 'log', level: 'info'})
], exceptionHandlers: [ new winston.transports.Console() ]
});
logger.log('info', "Running logs "+ d);
logger.info("Drive: "+ (new Date(d)).toDateString());
```

However when I try to query the data using:

```
winston.query(options, function (err, results) {
    if (err) {console.log(err);}
    console.log(results);
});
```

I get:

```
{}
```

It works for the Console correctly, and I am using the database in other parts of the application with the Mongoose library.

Comment: I am having the same issue. I am using MongoHQ with essentially the same code as above. Did you have any luck working it out?

Comment: unfortunately no. I end up doing without the mongodb considering it was not a core requirement and used a stream to write to a file. I am hoping to revisit the problem when work load clears up.

Answer (score 5):

I was having a similar issue. It turned out the problem for me was that the Winston MongoDB transport expects the host option to be just the host name and I was prefixing it with `mongodb://`.

The following works for me after removing `mongodb://` from `mongodb://123456.mongolab.com`:

```
var logger = new(winston.Logger)({
    transports : [
        new(winston.transports.MongoDB)({
            db : 'logs',
            host : '123456.mongolab.com',
            username : 'username',
            password : 'password'
        })
    ]
});
```

Comment: I am trying to try this out. +1 for hitting the target and a clean code.

Comment: With latest winston-mongodb you can now use dbUri option instead of host, port, dbname, etc.

Comment: @aarosil, just use `db` parameter to add everything, e.g. `db : 'mongodb://myuser:mypass@ds047777.mongolab.com:54545/MyLogDB`

Answer (score 3):

It should be so simple, it will be all in one line:

```
db : 'mongodb://myuser:mypass@ds047777.mongolab.com:54545/MyLogDB
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using this in 2021 this is an example of a logger.js using MONGODB

```
mongodb://<username>:<password>@mernshopping-shard-00-00.tzqom.mongodb.net:27017,mernshopping-shard-00-01.tzqom.mongodb.net:27017,mernshopping-shard-00-02.tzqom.mongodb.net:27017/myFirstDatabase?ssl=true&replicaSet=MernShopping-shard-0&authSource=admin&retryWrites=true&w=majority
```

```
const {createLogger, format, transports} =require('winston');
require('winston-mongodb');
const env= require('dotenv');
env.config();

const MONGO_URI = process.env.WINSTON_MONGODB_URI;

module.exports = createLogger({
    transports:[

 // File transport
    new transports.File({
    filename: 'logs/winstonLogs.log',
    format:format.combine(
        format.timestamp({format: 'MMM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss'}),
        format.align(),
        format.printf(info => `${info.level}: ${[info.timestamp]}: ${info.message}`),
    )}),
    new transports.MongoDB({
        level:'info',
        db: MONGO_URI,
        options:{
            useUnifiedTopology:true
        },
        collection:'server_logs',
        format:format.combine(
            format.timestamp(),
            //convert logs to a json format for mongodb
            format.json()
                )
    })
    ]
})
```